# C# file transfer with tcpclient and server

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

When I send a file with the code below, some data (small amout) is missing. The file size doess not match on the receiver side. Sending a regular string is fine so theres no connection issue here. Im just looking for a minimal improvement to fix the issue, I will add error checking etc later. Thanks! The code is mostly copied from some tutorial but i dont remember which though...

Client is the std .Net TcpClient class
Client.Client is it's socket

```
public void SendFile2(string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                byte[] lenBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)fs.Length);
                Client.Client.Send(lenBytes);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                fs.Position = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                    Client.Client.Send(buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
            }
        }

        public bool ReceiveFile2(string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];

                if (Client.Client.Receive(lenBytes) < 4)
                    return false;

                long len = BitConverter.ToInt32(lenBytes, 0);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = Client.Client.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                return len == fs.Position;
            }
        }
```

---

SOLUTION:

```
public void SendFile(string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            byte[] lenBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)fs.Length);
            Client.Client.Send(lenBytes);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            fs.Position = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                Client.Client.Send(buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
        }
    }

    public bool ReceiveFile(string fileName)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];

            if (Client.Client.Receive(lenBytes) < 4)
                return false;

            long len = BitConverter.ToInt32(lenBytes, 0);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

// Changed from here
            while (fs.Position < len)
            {
                bytesRead = Client.Client.Receive(buffer);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
// To here

            return len == fs.Position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: TCP you can receive a datagram with zero bytes.  Your while loop should change to read until the entire length of bytes are received.

Comment: Thanks jdweng, that did the trick. Posting the final code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line can be a problem.

`if (Client.Client.Receive(lenBytes) < 4)`
and 
`while ((bytesRead = Client.Client.Receive(buffer)) > 0)`

You have two receives in your code.

So you drop first bytes.
That can explain the differences you see in files sizes.

Comment: The point is that first you receive the file size (lenBytes) and then the file. It's supposed to make sure the file size becomes correct. But i'm unsure if it works in practice thoguh...

Comment: Ok, Know i understand what you tried to do, I have to read code slowly next times.